# Is there a way to merge textures in Unity in a shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, uv-mapping

I'm trying to animate a 2D game object using several overlaid layers of images in one mesh renderer. I've got several layers of different textures, each is an image with a transparent background.

I've found a way to programmatically create a rectangular mesh and layer the materials within it with UV mapping. Unfortunately Unity now has to render each of these material layers separately, despite the fact that they are all within one mesh. This results in a very inefficient number of draw calls. I can see that each material now has it's own shader as well.

Will I need to edit all of my images into one gigantic image outside of Unity and display portions of them using UV mapping in a single material within the mesh?

Or is there some way to achieve this with a shader?

Comment: yeah - what you want here is a **shader** that will mix them all in.

Comment: @Fattie, I'm very much a shader newbie. Would you be able to refer me to an example shader that can do this in Unity? Or perhaps some tutorials or docs to reference? Thank you.

Comment: @Mir - I can help, too. But we need more info. Unity Version? Render Pipeline? (Built-in, HDRP, URP (was called LWRP before)) etc. Do you prefer Code or Shadergraph? If you don't care at all, the simplest way would be to use ShaderGraph.

Comment: @KYL3R, I use the latest version of Unity, 2020.2.7 at the moment, with the built-in pipeline. I prefer code, but am planning to look into Shadergraph soon.

Comment: For Built-In Code shaders, Surface Shaders are easiest. (Compared to Vertex-Fragment Shaders). https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaderExamples.html. In your case, define multiple Inputs and add them with alpha as factor to layer them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create your own Shader (Code or ShaderGraph). Shaders can render multiple Textures (layers). You can blend by alpha/transprency however you like.

Edit: Example in ShaderGraph:
[image]

ShaderGraph Code:
https://pastebin.com/a8ubgxRP

```
application/vnd.unity.graphview.elements {
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.CopyPasteGraph",
    "m_ObjectId": "82a0e513542e4106ae94a0ba8a6ec750",
    "m_Edges": [
        {
            "m_OutputSlot": {
                "m_Node": {
                    "m_Id": "a58e7e104e604e0b9e2961da5510e2bf"
                },
                "m_SlotId": 0
            },
            "m_InputSlot": {
                "m_Node": {
                    "m_Id": "5e1616a6e87c470f8e3520b520b86bea"
                },
                "m_SlotId": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "m_OutputSlot": {
                "m_Node": {
                    "m_Id": "5e1616a6e87c470f8e3520b520b86bea"
                },
                "m_SlotId": 0
            },
            "m_InputSlot": {
                "m_Node": {
                    "m_Id": "b9bc9d71a2354d1ebadb93dab18e7223"
                },
                "m_SlotId": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "m_OutputSlot": {
                "m_Node": {
                    "m_Id": "e5668fa7ac4e42fdaa32049802bd78b2"
                },
                "m_SlotId": 0
            },
            "m_InputSlot": {
                "m_Node": {
                    "m_Id": "a275a2c058614973b0efd13817919cc6"
                },
                "m_SlotId": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "m_OutputSlot": {
                "m_Node": {
                    "m_Id": "a275a2c058614973b0efd13817919cc6"
                },
                "m_SlotId": 0
            },
            "m_InputSlot": {
                "m_Node": {
                    "m_Id": "b9bc9d71a2354d1ebadb93dab18e7223"
                },
                "m_SlotId": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "m_OutputSlot": {
                "m_Node": {
                    "m_Id": "a275a2c058614973b0efd13817919cc6"
                },
                "m_SlotId": 7
            },
            "m_InputSlot": {
                "m_Node": {
                    "m_Id": "b9bc9d71a2354d1ebadb93dab18e7223"
                },
                "m_SlotId": 3
            }
        }
    ],
    "m_Nodes": [
        {
            "m_Id": "5e1616a6e87c470f8e3520b520b86bea"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "a275a2c058614973b0efd13817919cc6"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "e5668fa7ac4e42fdaa32049802bd78b2"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "b9bc9d71a2354d1ebadb93dab18e7223"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "a58e7e104e604e0b9e2961da5510e2bf"
        }
    ],
    "m_Groups": [],
    "m_StickyNotes": [],
    "m_Inputs": [],
    "m_MetaProperties": [],
    "m_MetaPropertyIds": [],
    "m_MetaKeywords": [],
    "m_MetaKeywordIds": []
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.Vector1MaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "09a8291e17ab424e8149728df0325ac7",
    "m_Id": 5,
    "m_DisplayName": "G",
    "m_SlotType": 1,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "G",
    "m_StageCapability": 2,
    "m_Value": 0.0,
    "m_DefaultValue": 0.0,
    "m_Labels": []
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.Vector1MaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "09adddb00a6a45ba89f015d46cc7e777",
    "m_Id": 5,
    "m_DisplayName": "G",
    "m_SlotType": 1,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "G",
    "m_StageCapability": 2,
    "m_Value": 0.0,
    "m_DefaultValue": 0.0,
    "m_Labels": []
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.Vector4MaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "254965f8ab4b456789bf3701f105035f",
    "m_Id": 0,
    "m_DisplayName": "RGBA",
    "m_SlotType": 1,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "RGBA",
    "m_StageCapability": 2,
    "m_Value": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0,
        "w": 0.0
    },
    "m_DefaultValue": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0,
        "w": 0.0
    },
    "m_Labels": []
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.Vector1MaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "394d8ab6d6254442a22a1d2a1d393090",
    "m_Id": 4,
    "m_DisplayName": "R",
    "m_SlotType": 1,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "R",
    "m_StageCapability": 2,
    "m_Value": 0.0,
    "m_DefaultValue": 0.0,
    "m_Labels": []
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.SampleTexture2DNode",
    "m_ObjectId": "5e1616a6e87c470f8e3520b520b86bea",
    "m_Group": {
        "m_Id": ""
    },
    "m_Name": "Sample Texture 2D",
    "m_DrawState": {
        "m_Expanded": true,
        "m_Position": {
            "serializedVersion": "2",
            "x": -1229.6002197265625,
            "y": -552.0,
            "width": 208.0000762939453,
            "height": 433.6000061035156
        }
    },
    "m_Slots": [
        {
            "m_Id": "7f1789f703db4759a2c2cbbdcee37bb7"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "fdbf06e354c64748bc51ee1f630dec56"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "09a8291e17ab424e8149728df0325ac7"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "e3d48a7642ee490d9e52742319616c2a"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "6ea82df60cc64a08a6d75d13343fa8b3"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "fcc275cddbd44f6491e5c6752757e36f"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "6f90ea7d44914d0985b264b8fdd91f89"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "f9c9786a2bcd475d9ad02b23429c97f6"
        }
    ],
    "synonyms": [],
    "m_Precision": 0,
    "m_PreviewExpanded": true,
    "m_PreviewMode": 0,
    "m_CustomColors": {
        "m_SerializableColors": []
    },
    "m_TextureType": 0,
    "m_NormalMapSpace": 0
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.DynamicVectorMaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "5f0e671f32cf47cda2dbaf52f3591216",
    "m_Id": 2,
    "m_DisplayName": "Out",
    "m_SlotType": 1,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "Out",
    "m_StageCapability": 3,
    "m_Value": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0,
        "w": 0.0
    },
    "m_DefaultValue": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0,
        "w": 0.0
    }
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.Texture2DMaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "69f238b9d6ec46009f9ad1e06532c289",
    "m_Id": 0,
    "m_DisplayName": "Out",
    "m_SlotType": 1,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "Out",
    "m_StageCapability": 3,
    "m_BareResource": false
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.Vector1MaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "6a74085b28a4494f9928fbde7bb14ab4",
    "m_Id": 6,
    "m_DisplayName": "B",
    "m_SlotType": 1,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "B",
    "m_StageCapability": 2,
    "m_Value": 0.0,
    "m_DefaultValue": 0.0,
    "m_Labels": []
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.Vector1MaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "6ea82df60cc64a08a6d75d13343fa8b3",
    "m_Id": 7,
    "m_DisplayName": "A",
    "m_SlotType": 1,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "A",
    "m_StageCapability": 2,
    "m_Value": 0.0,
    "m_DefaultValue": 0.0,
    "m_Labels": []
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.UVMaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "6f90ea7d44914d0985b264b8fdd91f89",
    "m_Id": 2,
    "m_DisplayName": "UV",
    "m_SlotType": 0,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "UV",
    "m_StageCapability": 3,
    "m_Value": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0
    },
    "m_DefaultValue": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0
    },
    "m_Labels": [],
    "m_Channel": 0
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.DynamicVectorMaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "7d86c10d04514f1db34f1c03b5e0d07a",
    "m_Id": 0,
    "m_DisplayName": "Base",
    "m_SlotType": 0,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "Base",
    "m_StageCapability": 3,
    "m_Value": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0,
        "w": 0.0
    },
    "m_DefaultValue": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0,
        "w": 0.0
    }
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.Vector4MaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "7f1789f703db4759a2c2cbbdcee37bb7",
    "m_Id": 0,
    "m_DisplayName": "RGBA",
    "m_SlotType": 1,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "RGBA",
    "m_StageCapability": 2,
    "m_Value": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0,
        "w": 0.0
    },
    "m_DefaultValue": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0,
        "w": 0.0
    },
    "m_Labels": []
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.Texture2DMaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "9cf09bc550a4468faa6908e33854182c",
    "m_Id": 0,
    "m_DisplayName": "Out",
    "m_SlotType": 1,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "Out",
    "m_StageCapability": 3,
    "m_BareResource": false
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.UVMaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "9f7246d6f2f84e50a35232a424585f47",
    "m_Id": 2,
    "m_DisplayName": "UV",
    "m_SlotType": 0,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "UV",
    "m_StageCapability": 3,
    "m_Value": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0
    },
    "m_DefaultValue": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0
    },
    "m_Labels": [],
    "m_Channel": 0
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.SampleTexture2DNode",
    "m_ObjectId": "a275a2c058614973b0efd13817919cc6",
    "m_Group": {
        "m_Id": ""
    },
    "m_Name": "Sample Texture 2D",
    "m_DrawState": {
        "m_Expanded": true,
        "m_Position": {
            "serializedVersion": "2",
            "x": -1236.8001708984375,
            "y": -95.99998474121094,
            "width": 208.00001525878907,
            "height": 433.6000061035156
        }
    },
    "m_Slots": [
        {
            "m_Id": "254965f8ab4b456789bf3701f105035f"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "394d8ab6d6254442a22a1d2a1d393090"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "09adddb00a6a45ba89f015d46cc7e777"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "6a74085b28a4494f9928fbde7bb14ab4"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "de7a0347276243dca2e037c26fdd8b82"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "f18732f84c8f40849bb8eb7fc6d31fb6"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "9f7246d6f2f84e50a35232a424585f47"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "f08fa5b4eede46afad513c1f5cb4539e"
        }
    ],
    "synonyms": [],
    "m_Precision": 0,
    "m_PreviewExpanded": true,
    "m_PreviewMode": 0,
    "m_CustomColors": {
        "m_SerializableColors": []
    },
    "m_TextureType": 0,
    "m_NormalMapSpace": 0
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.Texture2DAssetNode",
    "m_ObjectId": "a58e7e104e604e0b9e2961da5510e2bf",
    "m_Group": {
        "m_Id": ""
    },
    "m_Name": "Texture 2D Asset",
    "m_DrawState": {
        "m_Expanded": true,
        "m_Position": {
            "serializedVersion": "2",
            "x": -1484.8001708984375,
            "y": -556.7999877929688,
            "width": 145.5999755859375,
            "height": 105.59998321533203
        }
    },
    "m_Slots": [
        {
            "m_Id": "9cf09bc550a4468faa6908e33854182c"
        }
    ],
    "synonyms": [],
    "m_Precision": 0,
    "m_PreviewExpanded": true,
    "m_PreviewMode": 0,
    "m_CustomColors": {
        "m_SerializableColors": []
    },
    "m_Texture": {
        "m_SerializedTexture": "{\"texture\":{\"instanceID\":0}}",
        "m_Guid": ""
    }
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.DynamicVectorMaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "aee1f01a0a34437095d6a66540ce346f",
    "m_Id": 1,
    "m_DisplayName": "Blend",
    "m_SlotType": 0,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "Blend",
    "m_StageCapability": 3,
    "m_Value": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0,
        "w": 0.0
    },
    "m_DefaultValue": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0,
        "w": 0.0
    }
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.BlendNode",
    "m_ObjectId": "b9bc9d71a2354d1ebadb93dab18e7223",
    "m_Group": {
        "m_Id": ""
    },
    "m_Name": "Blend",
    "m_DrawState": {
        "m_Expanded": true,
        "m_Position": {
            "serializedVersion": "2",
            "x": -852.800048828125,
            "y": -306.3999938964844,
            "width": 208.00001525878907,
            "height": 360.0
        }
    },
    "m_Slots": [
        {
            "m_Id": "7d86c10d04514f1db34f1c03b5e0d07a"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "aee1f01a0a34437095d6a66540ce346f"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "c868501ed3c14206b2d478b0ceb706bf"
        },
        {
            "m_Id": "5f0e671f32cf47cda2dbaf52f3591216"
        }
    ],
    "synonyms": [],
    "m_Precision": 0,
    "m_PreviewExpanded": true,
    "m_PreviewMode": 0,
    "m_CustomColors": {
        "m_SerializableColors": []
    },
    "m_BlendMode": 21
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.Vector1MaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "c868501ed3c14206b2d478b0ceb706bf",
    "m_Id": 3,
    "m_DisplayName": "Opacity",
    "m_SlotType": 0,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "Opacity",
    "m_StageCapability": 3,
    "m_Value": 1.0,
    "m_DefaultValue": 1.0,
    "m_Labels": []
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.Vector1MaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "de7a0347276243dca2e037c26fdd8b82",
    "m_Id": 7,
    "m_DisplayName": "A",
    "m_SlotType": 1,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "A",
    "m_StageCapability": 2,
    "m_Value": 0.0,
    "m_DefaultValue": 0.0,
    "m_Labels": []
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.Vector1MaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "e3d48a7642ee490d9e52742319616c2a",
    "m_Id": 6,
    "m_DisplayName": "B",
    "m_SlotType": 1,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "B",
    "m_StageCapability": 2,
    "m_Value": 0.0,
    "m_DefaultValue": 0.0,
    "m_Labels": []
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.Texture2DAssetNode",
    "m_ObjectId": "e5668fa7ac4e42fdaa32049802bd78b2",
    "m_Group": {
        "m_Id": ""
    },
    "m_Name": "Texture 2D Asset",
    "m_DrawState": {
        "m_Expanded": true,
        "m_Position": {
            "serializedVersion": "2",
            "x": -1501.6002197265625,
            "y": -96.79998779296875,
            "width": 145.60009765625,
            "height": 105.5999984741211
        }
    },
    "m_Slots": [
        {
            "m_Id": "69f238b9d6ec46009f9ad1e06532c289"
        }
    ],
    "synonyms": [],
    "m_Precision": 0,
    "m_PreviewExpanded": true,
    "m_PreviewMode": 0,
    "m_CustomColors": {
        "m_SerializableColors": []
    },
    "m_Texture": {
        "m_SerializedTexture": "{\"texture\":{\"instanceID\":0}}",
        "m_Guid": ""
    }
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.SamplerStateMaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "f08fa5b4eede46afad513c1f5cb4539e",
    "m_Id": 3,
    "m_DisplayName": "Sampler",
    "m_SlotType": 0,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "Sampler",
    "m_StageCapability": 3,
    "m_BareResource": false
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.Texture2DInputMaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "f18732f84c8f40849bb8eb7fc6d31fb6",
    "m_Id": 1,
    "m_DisplayName": "Texture",
    "m_SlotType": 0,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "Texture",
    "m_StageCapability": 3,
    "m_BareResource": false,
    "m_Texture": {
        "m_SerializedTexture": "{\"texture\":{\"instanceID\":0}}",
        "m_Guid": ""
    },
    "m_DefaultType": 0
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.SamplerStateMaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "f9c9786a2bcd475d9ad02b23429c97f6",
    "m_Id": 3,
    "m_DisplayName": "Sampler",
    "m_SlotType": 0,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "Sampler",
    "m_StageCapability": 3,
    "m_BareResource": false
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.Texture2DInputMaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "fcc275cddbd44f6491e5c6752757e36f",
    "m_Id": 1,
    "m_DisplayName": "Texture",
    "m_SlotType": 0,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "Texture",
    "m_StageCapability": 3,
    "m_BareResource": false,
    "m_Texture": {
        "m_SerializedTexture": "{\"texture\":{\"instanceID\":0}}",
        "m_Guid": ""
    },
    "m_DefaultType": 0
}

{
    "m_SGVersion": 0,
    "m_Type": "UnityEditor.ShaderGraph.Vector1MaterialSlot",
    "m_ObjectId": "fdbf06e354c64748bc51ee1f630dec56",
    "m_Id": 4,
    "m_DisplayName": "R",
    "m_SlotType": 1,
    "m_Hidden": false,
    "m_ShaderOutputName": "R",
    "m_StageCapability": 2,
    "m_Value": 0.0,
    "m_DefaultValue": 0.0,
    "m_Labels": []
}
```